# how to make traefik to bind host server's 80 and 443 port when using deployment type

Tags: kubernetes

I am using traefik 2.2.1 as my cluster's entrypoint using deployment type, this is my deployment config:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments/traefik
  uid: ddee327d-8570-44be-ab8d-06cb440187f4
  resourceVersion: '335024'
  generation: 12
  creationTimestamp: '2020-06-04T07:37:20Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
    helm.sh/chart: traefik-8.2.1
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '7'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: traefik
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
      app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
        helm.sh/chart: traefik-8.2.1
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: 'traefik:2.2.1'
          args:
            - '--global.checknewversion'
            - '--global.sendanonymoususage'
            - '--entryPoints.traefik.address=:9000'
            - '--entryPoints.web.address=:80'
            - '--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443'
            - '--api.dashboard=true'
            - '--ping=true'
            - '--providers.kubernetescrd'
            - '--providers.kubernetesingress'
          ports:
            - name: traefik
              containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
            - name: web
              containerPort: 8000
              protocol: TCP
            - name: websecure
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 1
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            runAsUser: 65532
            runAsGroup: 65532
            runAsNonRoot: true
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: traefik
      serviceAccount: traefik
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65532
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 12
  replicas: 5
  updatedReplicas: 2
  readyReplicas: 3
  availableReplicas: 3
  unavailableReplicas: 2
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2020-06-04T08:41:03Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-06-04T08:41:03Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2020-06-04T10:57:35Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-06-04T10:48:40Z'
      reason: ReplicaSetUpdated
      message: ReplicaSet "traefik-dd74b59b" is progressing.
```

my question is: is it possible to make the treafik listening host's 80 and 443 port? If possible, how to make it? or should I change my deployment type to daemon set? if not, I have to deployment a nginx in each node to forward traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `hostNetwork: true` in the spec. This makes the pod use host's network namespace.

```
...
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
    - name: traefik
...
```

Comment: I change the config and using this command to check the host's port's binding: `lsof -i:8000` but still no process listening,am I doing wrong something? @Arghya Sadhu

Comment: Checking in the node where the pod is running?

Comment: It works, I should using sudo to check it.@Arghya Sadhu